# Accessing XmlDataProvider defined in App.xaml in Utility class

Tags: wpf

I have a worker class which establishes a Two data bindings of some UI properties (like color) with XML Data source defined in App.xaml.

How I can access the XmlDataProvider defined in App.xaml in that worker class through the code?

App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="forum_propertiesDataSource" Source="\forum_properties.xml" d:IsDataSource="True"/>
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could access it this way anywhere in your project....

```
        var xmlDataProvider
            = Application.Current.TryFindResource(
                "forum_propertiesDataSource") as XmlDataProvider;
```